# As of the current date, what is the default /boot/config.txt

Tags: cmdline.txt

Could someone post the default cmdline.txt file as of the current version?

Comment: Why? By the time you have configured the Pi it will have changed, and by default does nothing. Just run raspi-config and set to your needs. If you want to see probable contents see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md

Comment: Also note the discrepancy between title and text: do you want to know the default config.txt or cmdline.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my `cmdline.txt` file from my 3B+ `stretch` RPi:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=serial0,115200 root=PARTUUID=bb8517b1-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

AFAIK, this is the "default"; at least I've never edited it directly.

Comment: But each download (the current 3 images) and NOOBS will differ and will differ from earlier images so copying this may result in an unbootable OS.

Comment: @Milliways: He asked a specific question, I answered as best I could. I've assumed he knows what he's doing. If I'm wrong, then he has an unbootable OS, and he has to d/l & write another image to his SD. Not the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks Seamus.  In fact, I could have done that very thing to get the original back as well, but I wished to avoid that.  As it turned out, I was able to learn what I needed about the root=PARTUUID= section, and look up the UUID and manually correct it.  I have been trying to get the Pi to boot from a hard drive, but no joy due to it taking longer than the 5 seconds available to come alive.  Appreciate the help, and info.  Good to know too Milliways.

Comment: @user3230518: "learning"... that's always a great word to hear! As far as your inability to boot from a HDD: I think you should be able to do this, but you may need something more than an entry in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. Have you looked at [this instruction on booting RPi from a HDD?](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-raspberry-pi-3-boot-usb/)

Comment: Actually, I got it to work finally.  It was easier to just have the boot and root partitions on that HD rather than boot on the SD.  Works great now. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Seamus BTW that link is really out of date.  :)

Comment: @user3230518: I've not tried it, but it looked OK... why do you feel it's OOD?